# flex-grow bug in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

If I decrease the value of flex-grow after increasing it, Chrome will make the item bigger instead of smaller.

You can see an example page at [https://gb.cs.unc.edu/~gb/tmp/bug.html](https://gb.cs.unc.edu/%7Egb/tmp/bug.html). I'll also include the code below.

**I've added Javascript to increment and decrement flex-grow on jsbin https://output.jsbin.com/puqolal/3**

If you open devtools on that page, and increase the value of flex-grow on the `div.choose-one` the buttons will grow. But when you decrease the value, they keep growing. It doesn't seem possible to reset back to the original state.

I'm, of course, adjusting the value from Javascript not devtools but I'm trying to minimize the code involved.

It renders as I would expect on Firefox. I have reported this as a potential Chrome bug but I'd love to find a work around until they fix it.

I'm using Chrome `Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flex bug?</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
      }
      div.choose-one {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
      div.hstack {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        height: 100%;
      }
      div.vstack {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      fieldset {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
      }
      button {
        flex: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hstack">
      <div class="vstack">
        <div class="choose-one" style="flex-grow: 1">
          <fieldset>
            <button>Me</button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="choose-one">
          <fieldset>
            <button>Present</button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is what flex-grow is suppose to do. What is your question?

Comment: Try it in chrome. When flex-grow is decreased the size of the button should decrease but instead it grows.

Comment: I can fix it by setting width and height to 100% on the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Add width: 100%; height: 100%; to the fieldset css and it works as expected.

I still think it is a bug in Chrome but this is a workaround.